# A following B with coordinate 100, -100

Tags: java, arrays

```
//intelligent next direction
//0 -> up, 1 -> right, 2 -> down, 3 -> left
static int nextIntelligent(int p1, int p2, int q1, int q2)
```

How can I do this with `IF` or `WHILE` form in java and the results will this at the end

```
 Intelligente Verfolgung
 Position A: (21, -2)
 Position B: (21, -2)
 Anzahl der Schritte: 24
```

I hope u will understand what i mean

Comment: "I hope u will understand what i mean" Unfortunately not. Take a few steps back. We don't have any context of what you're doing. You have been stuck on this problem for however long. We're looking at it with fresh eyes. Make this easier for us. A large part of getting an answer lies in accurately describing your problem.

Comment: B should now use a slightly smarter strategy (same start position of A and B as in part 1). If the distance of the first coordinates is greater than or equal to that of the second coordinates, the movement takes place along the first coordinate about a position in direction A, otherwise along the second coordinate in direction A. For this purpose, the method nextIntelligent is to be implemented, which determines the corresponding direction

Comment: You're still not giving us any context of what you're trying to accomplish. "slightly smarter strategy" **than what**? "If the distance of the first coordinates is" **coordinates of what**? A broad description of the problem is necessary to give context to the specifics of the problem.

Comment: im new in programming, and i have a homework, that tells so, i dont know now how to say that

Comment: Then your best bet is to ask your teacher or your classmates. They will have full context of the problem and will be able to help you. For future, read up on [how to ask a good question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bsp04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a1, a2, b1 = 0, b2 = 0, xA, yA, xB, yB;
        int pos, count = 0;

        //////// TEIL I

        System.out.print("1. Koordinate von A: ");
        a1 = SavitchIn.readLineInt();    
        System.out.print("2. Koordinate von A: ");
        a2 = SavitchIn.readLineInt();

        if (a1 > 100) {
            a1 = 100;
        }
        else if (a1 < -100) {
            a1 = -100;
        }

        if (a2 > 100) {
            a2 = 100;
        }

        else if (a2 < -100) {
            a2 = -100;
        }

        xA = a1;
        yA = a2;
        xB = b1;
        yB = b2;

        while(isSamePosition(a1, a2, b1, b2) == false){
            pos = nextDirection();

            if (pos == 0 && a2 < 100) {
                a2++;
                count++;

            }

            else if (pos == 1 && a1 < 100) {
                a1++;
                count++;

            }

            else if (pos == 2 && a2 > -100) {
                a2--;
                count++;
            }

            else if (pos == 3 && a1 > -100) {
                a1--;
                count++;
            }

            if (isSamePosition(a1, a2, b1, b2) == false) {
                pos = nextDirection();

                if (pos == 0 && b2 < 100) {
                    b2++;
                }

                else if (pos == 1 && b1 < 100) {
                    b1++;
                }
                else if (pos == 2 && b2 > -100) {
                    b2--;
                }

                else if (pos == 3 && b1 > -100) {
                    b1--;

                }

            }
        }


        System.out.println("Alles Zufall");
        System.out.println(" Position A: (" + a1 +", " + a2 +")");
        System.out.println(" Position B: (" + b1 +", " + b1 +")");
        System.out.println(" Anzahl der Schritte: " + count);
        }

        static int nextDirection(){
            int random = PRNG.randomInt(4);
            return random;
            }

        static boolean isSamePosition (int p1, int p2, int q1, int q2){
            boolean same = false;

            if (p1 == q1 && p2 == q2) {
                same = true;
            }

            return same;
        }


        static int nextIntelligent(int xA, int yA, int xB, int yB){

            return -1;
        }
    }
```